# Can the Dominated Convergence Theorem and MCT be used for limits to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I saw a solution to the problem

> $$ \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \int_{\alpha}^{1+\alpha} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2 + \alpha^2}$$

that involved simply by moving the limit inside the integral which simplifies to an elementary integral that further gives the limit of $\frac\pi 4$. That is:

$$\lim_{\alpha \to 0} \int_{\alpha}^{1+\alpha} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2 + \alpha^2} =  \int_{\alpha}^{1+\alpha} \lim_{\alpha \to 0} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2 + \alpha^2} = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{dx}{1 + x^2} = \arctan1 - \arctan0 = \dfrac \pi 4 $$

There are no remarks explaining why it is allowed to move the limit in this case. As far as I know, the monotone convergence theorem and the dominated convergence theorem allow us to do this when we have infinite limits, as explained in the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253696/can-a-limit-of-an-integral-be-moved-inside-the-integral).
In this case, by what theorem is it allowed?

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3412510/using-dominated-convergence-theorem-with-continuous-limits, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2681712/extending-the-dominated-convergence-theorem-to-continuous-limits.

Comment: If you want to use the DCT, you better mention a dominating function.

Comment: @Thorgott I know that. My question is that, since the limit in the question is not to infinity, as is in the condition for DCT, doesn't that mean we can't use DCT in this case?

Comment: My remark was just for the sake of completeness. See Calvin's answer for the main question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things -

1. you need a change of variables $y=x-\alpha$ to move the $\alpha$ out of the integration limits. In particular $\int_\alpha^{1+\alpha} \lim_{\alpha\to 0}$ is nonsense. An alternative is to write the integration limits as multiplication with an indicator $\mathbb 1_{[\alpha,1+\alpha]}$
2. To apply the usual sequential DCT/MCT, use the sequential formulation of the limit. Let $\alpha_n \to 0$ be arbitrary. Then what you need is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{dy}{1+(y+\alpha_n)^2 +\alpha_n^2}$ which is amenable to textbook versions of the theorems

Comment: What is the *sequential formulation of the limit* ?

Comment: $f(x)\to c$ as $x\to y$ iff for every sequence $x_n\to y$ as $n\to\infty$, we have $f(x_n) \to c$ as $n\to\infty$ @E.Nole

Comment: Could you fill in the steps starting from the change of variable? I'm still not quite clear on how to get to the form in step 2.

Comment: When I set $y=x+\alpha$ I still have $\alpha$ in the limits i.e  $\lim_{y \to x} \int_{2\alpha}^{1+ 2 \alpha} \frac{dy}{1+(y-\alpha)^2 +\alpha^2}$

Comment: @E.Nole that should have been a minus sign not a plus sign, sorry